# can't change Skeletal Mesh in UE4

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

Actually, I was trying to change the skeletal mesh of car in UE4, in the wheeled vehicle demo project which comes in ue4 c++ API.
Firstly I inherited blueprint from ue4 wheeled vehicle c++ class.
Then I opened blueprint editor and replaced default skeletal mesh to my skeletal mesh.
I assigned bone names correctly.
Then everything was in its place(according to me)
Then I recompiled.
Then I placed blueprint in level and possess it. But when I clicked W,A,S,D keys it doesn't work. And the car doesn't move at all.

If I am doing any mistake, please guide me through steps and how can I resolve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The animation blueprint is also tied to a specific Skeleton. If your new skeletal mesh uses a different skeleton than the one currently assigned to your skeletal mesh component, then you will need to create a new corresponding animation blueprint to use with it.

Comment: Yes, animations shouldn't work but what about movement. It should work(?). But its not working!

Comment: not sure about that in the case of wheeled vehicle. The movement is physics based. You did also create a new physics asset with the proper setup, yes? (kinematic wheel bones)

Comment: Yes, I will repeat the whole process one more time, maybe I have did some mistake. I am wondering If I should have committed any mistake In creating bone or something? will that be a problem because vehicle is not responding when I press input keys. Means it should respond  in some way as vechile movement component is applying throttle, but it's not showing any kind of activity.

Comment: Also make sure the orientation of your mesh and every bone in the mesh is identical to what the system expects - compare it to the demo asset for reference, e.g. wheel bones local orientation should be x forward, y to driver's right, z up

Comment: Also I followed a tutorial https://youtu.be/qCSN1oScO4E which is about creating a wheeled vechile  with the help of "WheeledVechileMovementComponent4W" and I did everything in the right way, but after I assign skeletal mesh and try to test it it does not move. To check that Input bindings are hooked up correctly I also created a log output from those functions which were being called and it showed log messages correctly when I pressed keys means everything work fine in code. I think I literally rigged the vehicle wrong way because none of the method is working...

Comment: Seems that my skeletal mesh was not correctly rigged, I tried using vehicle form vehicle variety pack (from Epic Store), and it works fine.